# How to setup my Android wifi config for vpn sharing using astrill?

Tags: vpn, ip-address

https://wiki.astrill.com/Astrill_Setup_Manual:Enable_VPN_Sharing

I am trying to enable VPN sharing from my computer to my Android device. I got to the step where I change the IP Settings from DHCP to Static. I entered the IP address in Gateway, DNS1 and DNS2 as instructed.

However, I am unable to save because the `IP address` field is missing. Does anyone know what to enter and where to find it?

[image]

Comment: Maybe this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mnbit.android.ipchangerhistory) helps?

Comment: You need a free static IP in your local subnet. Check your router which IP addresses in the range of 192.168.46.x are assigned for DHCP and from the remaining select a free IP.